# Cannot output data to text file inside IF statement, C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file-io, fstream, ofstream

I am trying to output distance and time data in my text file, "Data.txt", inside an `if` statement. I know that the actions inside the `if` statement are being performed because I can see the words "Hello!" and "distance: 5 time: 0" printing in my "Immediate Window" (using Visual Studio 2017), but my text file Data.txt is blank! I have arbitrarily set distance = 5 and time = 0 to make my code simpler to debug.

```
//opening data file to write to
ofstream datafile("Data.txt");

if (HandClosedOnTarget(rightHandState, rightHandPosition, targetPositions[currentTargetIndex]))
        {
        secondsPassed = 0;
        distance = 5;

        datafile << "time (sec): " << secondsPassed << " distance: " << distance << "\n";

        TRACE(L"Hello!\n");
        TRACE(L"distance = %s time: %s \n", std::to_wstring(distance).c_str(), std::to_wstring(secondsPassed).c_str());
        }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure your looking at the right file?  The default directory is `Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Project Name\Project Name`

Comment: also, is that the only problem you are facing?  Or does your program crash further down?

Comment: @NathanOliver I believe I am looking at the right file

Comment: @MikeNakis this is the only problem I'm facing

Comment: Do you properly close your file when you are done with it and before your program terminates?

Comment: @MikeNakis I have not! I will try that. Thank you